# Datastax Cassandra PHP extension in WAMP

Tags: php, cassandra, wamp, datastax, php-extension

I am using WAMP with php v5.5.12.
Trying to install datastax php driver(https://github.com/datastax/php-driver).
1. I take the compiled dll file from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/cassandra/1.0.1/windows)  and put it in /ext folder
2. Add the extention=php_cassandra.dll to php.ini
3. Restarting WAMP server

I get this error in wamp php error log:

> [28-Jan-2016 07:32:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_cassandra.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Also installed Pear package, but there are no changes.
Does anyone here experience with cassandra new driver on windows?
What can be the problem?

Comment: Typo: `extention=php_cassandra.dll` → `extension=php_cassandra.dll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not either make the .dll found on the pecl php site work.  Same error.

But the .dll found here works!

http://downloads.datastax.com/php-driver/windows/cassandra/

Comment: Thank you! I still can not connect to server, but it is another issue.

Comment: Same issue. Pecl library doesn't work for some reason

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `Thread Safe` version (TS) and of course the one for PHP5.5. Also you need to use the x86 if you WAMPServer is the 32 bit and the x64 if WAMPServer is the 64bit version

That dll should be place into the  `\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext` folder

Comment: oops, forgot to mention it. I am using the correct dll file, as when not doing it I received an error about it. And for sure I am placing it in the right place (\ext\)